# python import statement fails in function

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I have a python module that needs to be able to run on Windows and Linux.  While running it responds to certain keyboard "hotkeys".  It is a python 3.3 script.

In my class constructor I do the following:

```
self.setup_stdin()
```

The function `setup_stdin` is this:

```
def setup_stdin(self):
    self.osname = os.name
    if self.osname == 'posix':
        self.setup_posix_stdin()
    elif self.osname == 'nt':
        self.setup_nt_stdin()
```

When I run on Linux, I have no problem with `setup_posix_stdin`, it just makes `stdin` non-blocking so I can handle keystrokes.

`setup_nt_stdin` is the following:

```
def setup_nt_stdin(self):
    import msvcrt
```

However, when I run on Windows 7, my program bombs with

```
NameError: global name 'msvcrt' is not defined
```

To get around this, when I run on Windows, I move the import statement to the top of the file, and replace the `setup_nt_stdin` function body with pass,  and it works fine.

I thought I could import from a function. This function is inside a class, is there some other syntax I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `import` statement binds the name of the imported module in the local scope only.

To get around this you could do:

```
def setup_nt_stdin(self):
    global msvcrt
    import msvcrt
```

Although considering you can `import` something multiple times without it executing any more and you're going to need guards to check the OS before actually using the name `msvcrt` elsewhere, it might make more sense to just `import msvcrt` inside every windows-specific function that needs it.

Comment: Well, since I have only one function that uses msvcrt, I chose your latter solution, which is just to import in that function.  So, my setup_nt_stdin just becomes a pass.  In Linux I needed to do some stuff to setup stdin to make it non-blocking, so at the time I also created a setup_nt_stdin, then I found out it didn't really need to do anything, but I knew I was going to need msvcrt, so I thought, heh, I'll import it there.  I was mistaken about the scope an import statment had.  Thanks.